# Deleting sheets with a combo box

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there i have been working on a code to delete sheets with the use of a combo box but i  do not seem to be able to run it . I have used the deletesheet sub to call the userform so that the combo box will display and i can choose and delete the sheets. However I have been getting a type mismatch error on *Worksheets(a).Delete* ( I have put the asterisks for reference purposes i ran the programme without those)

```
 Private Sub setUserForm()
    With UserForm1
        .Height = 50:   .Width = 111
        .Caption = " Delete Sheets"
        With .ComboBox1
            .BackColor = RGB(240, 250, 255)
            .ControlTipText = "Select Sheet"
            .Height = 17:   .Width = UserForm1.Width - 15
            .Top = 7:       .Left = 7:  .ListRows = 22
            .MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryFirstLetter   '0
        End With
        .Show
    End With
End Sub


Sub deletesheet()
    Dim a As String  'This is changed
    Dim cmb As ComboBox
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set cmb = UserForm1.ComboBox1
    cmb.Clear
      For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Visible Then cmb.AddItem ws.Name

        Next

    a = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Text   'This is changed
    *Worksheets(a).delete*
       cmb.ListIndex = 0
         setUserForm
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? and from what i can see so far you are defining `Dim a as Integer` then passing it the value from `UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value` but the `ComboBox1.Value` is a String not an Integer

Comment: Dim a As String instead of Integer should fix the problem - I think

Comment: I get a subscript out of range error at  Worksheets(a).delete @O.Rose

Comment: @Niva there is no need to define A you can simply do Worksheets(UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value).Delete

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
a = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following:

```
Sub deletesheet()
    Dim a As String  'This is changed
    Dim cmb As ComboBox

    Set cmb = UserForm1.ComboBox1
    cmb.Clear

    a = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Text   'This is changed
    Worksheets(a).Delete

End Sub
```

These changes are required because you have filled the ComboBox with worksheet names which are strings. ComboBox1.Text will then return the specific string selected and so it must be stored in a string variable